# I would like to host an ethereum swarm server backed by s3

Tags: amazon-s3, ethereum, swarm

I would like to run an ethereum node and swarm server but instead of writing files to the local file system (beyond caching) it would read/write from an s3 bucket.

Is this possible today? From looking in [`go-ethereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/swarm/storage/netstore.go) codebase it looks like there may be some abstractions in place but I didn't see anything specifically related to s3.

I would be happy to contribute code to this repo or make my own addon if that was possible. Could anyone give me a pointer to documentation on how to accomplish this and a brief overview of what would be needed? Again, I'd be happy to contribute to existing projects if that was wanted or appropriate.